# Orbeon - Multi-language template HTTP Service request

Tags: http, service, orbeon, multilingual

On a multi-language template I use a HTTP service to load a list of countries from a web service. The loading itself is done by an action that reacts to the Form Load event.

Since the names of the countries are different in each language, I would like to pass a parameter to the web service that specifies the language of the user.
Another option would be to select the correct label after the list has been loaded.

Unfortunately I don't have any clue on how to achieve this. Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you tell us if this for a form you created with Form Builder, or for a form that you wrote directly in XForms?

Comment: This is a form created with Form Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to pass the language to the web service by editing the source code manually. I added the language as web service request parameter with the following xml (added to the action).

```
<xforms:action context="instance('fr-service-request-instance')">
    <xforms:action class="fr-set-service-value-action">
        <xxforms:variable name="control-name" select="'requestor_country'" as="xs:string"/>
        <xxforms:variable name="path" select="//*:language" as="xs:string"/>
        <xforms:setvalue ref="$path" value="xxforms:instance('fr-language-instance')"/>
    </xforms:action>                
</xforms:action>
```

I still have one problem though, when the user switches language, the values are not loaded and the list is empty.

Currently the country list is loaded on the xforms-ready event. Which one should be used when switching language ?

Comment: Find the name of your submission (this is the `id` on the `<xforms:submission>`) and add, somewhere under `<xforms:model>` the following (which you can reformat as desired to make this more readable): `<xforms:action ev:observer="fr-language-selector" ev:event="DOMActivate"><xforms:send submission="yahoo-weather-submission"/></xforms:action>`. This will "listen" on users changing the language, and when they do also call your service.

Comment: I can't get this to work. I've added the following just before </xforms:model> : <xforms:action ev:event="fr-language-selector" ev:observer="DOMActivate"> <xforms:send submission="Countries-submission"/> </xforms:action> where Countries-submission is the id of my submission. I checked the logs and found out the web service isn't called when switching language.

Comment: OK, let's take it step by step. First, let's see if the listener is called. If you add `<xforms:action ev:observer="fr-language-selector" ev:event="DOMActivate"><xforms:message>Language changed</xforms:message></xforms:action>` inside the `<xforms:model>`, then test the form, and switch language, do you see the message displayed? (I tried this with a 3.9 PE release build, and I do see it.)

Comment: I'll do. Unfortunately I can't do this until wednesday next week.

Comment: OK, no problem; thanks for the update, and you'll let us know if this works.